# ActiveX control tab order in an Excel spreadsheet - is it possible to access/control this from script?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, ms-office

I have embedded a number of ActiveX controls in an Excel 2007 spreadsheet. Is there a way from VBA code to access the tab order assigned to a control so that the controls can be tabbed through in a particular order? The ActiveX controls I have inserted tab through in the insertion order, but this is not correct after changes have been made to the application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your updating the controls frequently.  I have failed to find a way to change the tab order on embedded controls as well.  Only other option, other than rebuilding the form in the correct sort oder, would be to create your own form, then just call it open with a single embedded button.